# How to exclude applied groups from report

Tags: maven, jqassistant

I am using jqassistant 1.2.0 with asciidoc 1.5.3 - all in maven. 
My question is a specific question for the maven plugin "jqassistant". I am scanning a large java war from a server using "mvn clean install" as the default command line prompt.

I need "classpath:Resolve" in my analysis (so that all links between nodes are generated). However i don't want the concepts of that to show up in the report... is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you provide more information on what the problem is you're having, which language, which environment and what the code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not yet possible but would be a good enhancement for upcoming needed changes to the reporting part of jQAssistant. It's already possible to add a report type to rules and it would be possible to provide something like reportType="none". It would be required to inherit that property within groups in case of pre-defined rules like "classpath:Resolve".